# PHP (windows), virtuoso, SPARQL, UTF-8 (Russian) does not work

Tags: utf-8, sparql

Currently I’m working with a project on virtuoso and php (windows7 (64)),

“insert” (sparql query) of triples in Virtuoso does not work with Russian (UTF-8)

```
 $iquery = "sparql INSERT DATA INTO <http://example.net/Empl> {<http://example.net/empl1> <http://example.net/firstname> 'Русский язык'.}";
```

The following query works in English, but when a line appears in Russian (UTF-8), PHP returns an error

```
 *Warning*: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec <http://localhost:8890/test/admin/function.odbc-exec>]: SQL error:  [OpenLink][Virtuoso ODBC Driver][Virtuoso Server]SQ074: Line 1: Bad  escape sequence in a SPARQL short single-quoted string at '\', SQL state  37000 in SQLExecDirect in*C:\virtuoso-opensource\vsp\test\admin\index.php*on line*164*
```

What can you offer for me to do?

Thanks,
 Sergey

PS sparql query “insert” works with Russian (UTF-8) in isql

Comment: UTF8 is UTF8. There's no "Russian UTF8"

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `SQL_UTF8_EXECS = 1` as detailed at http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/dbadm.html#ini_Client?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your ODBC connection string correctly in order for Virtuoso to accept UTF-8 properly

Have you included the `Charset=utf-8` parameter in your connection string?

If you have and you still experience this problem then you should likely contact the Virtuoso developers for further assistance